# Is there any missing configuration while running npx playwright test

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, playwright, playwright-test

I have been working on playwright axe web accessibility test on reactjs web application, below is the code using playwright and axe. When I try running command "npx playwright axe" in terminal, it runs App.test.ts and if I provide path then it displays Running 0 tests using 0 workers.

```
//a11y.specs.ts
import { chromium, Browser, Page } from "playwright";
import { test } from "@playwright/test";
import { injectAxe, checkA11y } from "axe-playwright";

let browser: Browser;
let page: Page;

test.describe("Playwright web page accessibility test", () => {
  test.beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await chromium.launch();
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.w3.org/WAI/demos/after/before/news.html');
    await injectAxe(page);
  });

  test("simple accessibility run", async () => {
    await checkA11y(page);
  });
});

cmd - npx playwright test

project structure- 

Client -
   - node_modules
   - src
   - a11ytests
     - a11y.specs.ts
   - playwright.config.js
   - package.json

//file - playwright.config.js

const config = {
  timeout: 30000,
  globalTimeout: 600000,
  reporter: "list",
  testDir: "./a11ytests",
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: where does the test `a11y.specs.ts` exist in your project? Would be good if you can add a screenshot of the project structure showing your `playwright.config.ts` file and your `a11y.specs.ts` file.

Comment: @AlapanDas added project structure

Comment: Can you include your config as well.

Answer (score 1):

So `npx playwright test` is by default configured to find tests inside the `tests` folder. But if you have a different folder name, you have to provide the path like this:

```js
npx playwright test a11ytests/a11y.specs.ts
```

In your `playwright.config.ts` file by default, you can see something like this:

```js
testDir: './tests',
```

Change the value to:

```js
testDir: './a11ytests'
```

This is an example of my `playwright.config.ts` file

```js
import { PlaywrightTestConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';

/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {

  testDir: './tests',

  /* Maximum time one test can run for. */
  timeout: 30 * 1000,

  expect: {

    /**
     * Maximum time expect() should wait for the condition to be met.
     * For example in `await expect(locator).toHaveText();`
     */
    timeout: 5000
  },

  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,

  /* Retry on CI only */
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,

  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,

  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: 'html',

  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {

    /* Maximum time each action such as `click()` can take. Defaults to 0 (no limit). */
    actionTimeout: 0,

    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    // baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',

    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: 'on-first-retry',

    //Capture Screenshot on failure
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',

      /* Project-specific settings. */
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
      },
    },

    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Firefox'],
      },
    },

    {
      name: 'webkit',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Safari'],
      },
    },

    /* Test against mobile viewports. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Chrome',
    //   use: {
    //     ...devices['Pixel 5'],
    //   },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Mobile Safari',
    //   use: {
    //     ...devices['iPhone 12'],
    //   },
    // },

    /* Test against branded browsers. */
    // {
    //   name: 'Microsoft Edge',
    //   use: {
    //     channel: 'msedge',
    //   },
    // },
    // {
    //   name: 'Google Chrome',
    //   use: {
    //     channel: 'chrome',
    //   },
    // },
  ],

  /* Folder for test artifacts such as screenshots, videos, traces, etc. */
  // outputDir: 'test-results/',

  /* Run your local dev server before starting the tests */
  // webServer: {
  //   command: 'npm run start',
  //   port: 3000,
  // },
};
export default config;
```

Comment: Can you tell what should be inside playwright.config.ts file

Comment: Running 0 tests using 0 workers
=================
 no tests found.
=================


To open last HTML report run:

  npx playwright show-report                                 is this expected result?

Comment: And you are running the command from the project root where the playwright config file exists?

Comment: Yes running in the same Client folder,  is there any installation for npx playwright test install

Comment: You can try running `npx playwright install`. These install the browsers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247747/discussion-between-abhishek-konnur-and-alapan-das).